# How do I increase the -QueryTimeOut parameter in MS SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have two servers running Microsoft SQL 2008 and I am using Merge replication.  It uses a push subscription.  The other day there was an event that would have caused more rows to be inserted into the database then normal.  Between 5,000 and 10,000 rows would have been inserted into three tables over the course of 5 minutes.  In the next 14 hours I got about 80 e-mails with this error message:

> The Merge Agent failed to retrieve
>   article information for publication
>   'Lynx'. Increase the -QueryTimeOut
>   parameter and restart the
>   synchronization. When troubleshooting,
>   use SQL Profiler or restart the agent
>   with a higher value for
>   -HistoryVerboseLevel a

After I restarted the agent and reinitialized replication, the errors stopped.

So, how do I increase the -QueryTimeOut parameter?  And, will it help prevent this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can do this from Replication Monitor (right-click the "Replication" node in Management Studio, and choose Launch Replication Monitor).

Select your publication, right click the subscription in the list to the right, and choose "Agent Profile". You can either edit the "Default agent profile" or create a new one. Either way, you can modify the -QueryTimeout parameter if you click the little ellipsis button to edit the profile.

Disclaimer: I've never had to actually change this, but it certainly looks promising.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  It looks like I cannot edit the "Default agent profile" but I can create a new one.  Then I just need to "Change Existing Agents" to use the new profile.  I'm assuming I will need to restart the agent after this.

Comment: If it's set to run continuously, then yeah, you'll probably have to restart the agent. If it's just set to a recurring/manual schedule, then I would guess that the changes will take effect the next time it starts running.